# Neo4j: How to select users

Tags: database, neo4j

I have nodes like this:

User --is in--> Group <---teaches-- Lecturer

So, we have Lecturer who teaches group of users. There are labels User, Group, Lecturer. And specific values: 
Users: John, Jane, Caleb; 
Group: A1; 
Lecturer: Mike

How can I select all users whose lecturer is Mike ? Lecturer can teaches in more than one group of students.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the students who have been taught by Mike and nothing in between then you can use:

```
MATCH (mike:Lecturer{name:"Mike"})-[:LECTURES]->()<-[:IS_IN]-(user:User)
RETURN DISTINCT(user)
```